# Is there a single word that means bringing something up to standard?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, synonyms

> To queer people for whom it is unsafe to come out, I say, I am so sorry.  You are beautiful, you are handsome, you are normal, you are wonderful, you are precious, and you are worthy.  Whether you are out or not.  The closet is the worst prison, and I my deepest desire for you is that your world is soon *brought up to standard*, that you will have the freedom to be who you were meant to be, the freedom to love yourself.

I'm looking for a word to replace *brought up to standard*.  The best I can come up with is *cured*, but cured means that it was once already in a healthy state, and is being restored to it; that is not the case in my scenario.

I want a word that means to mature and to make right something that has never been right.  The word might be *rectify*, but onomatopoetically, that sounds too ... mechanical?

Ideas?

Comment: *My* idea is that ***rectify*** might be the best you're gonna get here. It seems to me every single-word term with the general sense of *improve **to some [pre-established] adequate standard*** will carry a strong implication that we know what the necessary "adequate standard" is *because it did actually exist in the past, so now only needs to be "recovered", not created from scratch*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's the word I went with.

Comment: if you're prepared to go with multi-word terms, ***sufficiently improved*** pretty much carries the sense you want without implying *returning* to some more optimal condition in the past. But the "trickiness" of the context even comes through there (how to define "sufficiently" if there's no preceding example of what we're aiming for, given that *having the freedom to be who you were meant to be* is ridiculously vague! :)

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was *normalized*.

> **Normalize**
> verb
>
> 1. bring or return to a normal or standard condition or state. "the situation had normalized"

[[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/normalize)

Answer (score 0):

"...and I my deepest desire for you is that your world..."

- ...**will soon merge with mainstream culture**.

[**merge**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/merge) - "combine or cause to combine to form a single entity."

Comment: Hmm.  Mainstream culture in America, unfortunately, is homophobic and transphobic.  At least it feels that way to me.

Comment: It only feels like that to you because most mainstream media constantly pumps out the message that everyone in the country (apart from them and their audience / readership) is seriously problematic. And they only do that because it sells newspapers and airtime, not because it reflects anything about the real world, or what real people think.

Comment: @dx_over_dt  The dissipation of all prejudice is a sine qua non for the merge.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it feels that way to me because I have been rejected by loved ones and taunted by strangers